# Replace an integer value with a string when displaying in a view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i have view like this :

```
@model IEnumerable<PMS.Models.Activity_Contractor>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPageArchitect.cshtml";
  }

 <h2>Index</h2>

 <p>
   @*@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")*@
  </p>
<table>
<tr>
     @*<th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.A_C_ID)
    </th>*@

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayName("ProjectName")
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProjectActivityMaster.ActivityName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ContractorMaster.ContractorName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsActive)
    </th>
  @*  <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedON)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UpdatedBy)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UpdatedON)
    </th>*@
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    @*<td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.A_C_ID)
    </td>*@
    <td>
        @Html.Label("Project")
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectActivityMaster.ActivityName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContractorMaster.ContractorName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsActive)
    </td>
   @* <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedBy)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedON)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UpdatedBy)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UpdatedON)
    </td>*@
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.A_C_ID  }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.A_C_ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.A_C_ID })
    </td>
     </tr>
}

 </table>
```

my item.IsActive value used to be 1/0 i want saw it as True if 1 and False id 0. how can i do that ?

Comment: Is `IsActive` of boolean type?

Comment: nop INT which contains 1/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my item.IsActive value used to be 1/0 i want saw it as True if 1 and
>   False id 0. how can i do that ?
>
> INT which contains 1/0

If you want total control over what you can show then it's best that you use a display template.

### Create A Template

Create a folder called `DisplayTemplates` under the `Shared` folder, if you still don't have it. Then create a file called `CustomInt.cshtml`, you can of course choose any name you want **except** those names that are similar to data types (e.g. Int, Boolean, etc). Then on the template you need to have this:

```
@model System.Int32

@if (Model == 0)
{
    @:True
}
else if (Model==1) {
    @:False
}
```

### How You Use It

Then on your view where you want to show `IsActive` you need to do this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.IsActive, "CustomInt")
```

Notice that we specified a template name to html helper.

### Pitfall

You need to be very careful in using the template. Since `IsActive` is an int then it can have a value other than `0` and `1`. So if the value is other than those two then nothing will print out. But that's not a big issue though as you can easily add another `else` and print an error or something else. But I think you are pretty sure that `IsActive` will always have either `0` or `1`.

The modified template to catch unexpected value:

```
@model System.Int32

@if (Model == 0)
{
    @:True
}
else if (Model==1) {
    @:False
}
else {
    @:What is this value? The system was hacked!
}
```

Comment: Awesome @von v. Great Answer with Explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

You could parse your IsActive on your viewmodel to return true or false.

```
public class Myviewmodel
{
    public string IsActive { get; set; }

}

public class Mymodel
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

then parse your booleans to strings when mapping them from your model to your viewmodel?

Tip : Try using NBuilder